# Variable not initialized... but it was?

Tags: java

So the application I am working on at the moment requires 3 methods that return values to another class. The issue I'm having is with my second method that associates the users' input from the first method with the corresponding Named month. I continuously receive a "variable might not have been initialized" error from this set:

```
public String MonthName(int monthNumber){
    /*This method assigns a Name based on the users input and
    **returns the proper name of the corresponding month 
    ** @para: monthNameFin is the final name of the month
    **        rest should be self-explanatory              */

    String monthNameFin;

    if (monthNumber == 1)
        monthNameFin = "January";
    if (monthNumber == 2)
        monthNameFin = "February";
    if (monthNumber == 3)
        monthNameFin = "March";
    if (monthNumber == 4)
        monthNameFin = "April";
    if (monthNumber == 5)
        monthNameFin = "May";
    if (monthNumber == 6)
        monthNameFin = "June";
    if (monthNumber == 7)
        monthNameFin = "July";
    if (monthNumber == 8)
        monthNameFin = "August";
    if (monthNumber == 9)
        monthNameFin = "September";
    if (monthNumber == 10)
        monthNameFin = "October";
    if (monthNumber == 11)
        monthNameFin = "November";
    if (monthNumber == 12)
        monthNameFin = "December";

    return monthNameFin;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when `monthNumber` equals anything else?

Comment: What happens if ``monthNumber`` is 13?

Comment: You need a default and also you should use if/else if/else if

Comment: Needs to use a `switch...case`, rather.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but your code can be simply improved for instance by using arrays. Create one array (or enum) with months and use `months[i]` to get correct month (or `[i-1]`) if `i` should be in range `1-12` while array range is `0-11`. You will have to test if `i` is correct value (is in correct range) but this would be just one `if` compared to twenty you have now.

Comment: We are still early on in the class and they are holding our hands, walking us down the isle of kindergarten coding before they branch us out into "real-world" coding for a lack of better expression : /

But i definitely appreciate the feedback. Arrays are in two weeks I believe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the possibility that none of your cases matches, if `monthNumber` is less than or equal to 0, or if it's 13 or greater.  This means that there is a possibility of the variable not being initialized.

Because numbers outside the range of 1-12 don't make sense, it's better to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` at the bottom if no case matches.

This example also includes changing all case assignment statements to `return` statements, so that there is a `return` or a `throw` for every case, even for the unmatched case.

```
  ...
  if (monthNumber == 12)
      return "December";

  // No case matched.
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad month number: " + monthNumber);
}
```

The code that calls this method should catch this exception and handle it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any chance you have an example? That is a new concept to me altogether.

Comment: So... I tried this and I'm getting an "unreachable statement" on my return value now... any ideas?

Comment: Oops, there needs to be a return or a throw for every case.  Fixed again.

Comment: Great! Is there any way to get this error message in a dialog window using JOptionPane?

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize the variable as :

```
String monthNameFin=null;
```

or

```
String monthNameFin="";
```

else if you have always an assignment of value you can skip the initialization, for example:

```
String monthNameFin;
   if (monthNumber == 1){
        monthNameFin = "January";
   }else{ 
        monthNameFin = "January";
   }
```

in this case there is no escape... to monthNumberFin will be in any case a value, while in your code it might happen that it never enters an if .. assuming it is for example montthumber=14

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers stated, you have to initialized your variable.

But instead of all this `if`, I would use a [`DateFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) object.

```
public String MonthName(int monthNumber){
     if(monthNumber < 1 || monthNumber > 12)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Month must be in the range [1, 12]");
     DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.UK);
     return dfs.getMonths()[monthNumber-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to write this that handles all integer cases:

```
public String monthName(int monthNumber) {
    if (monthNumber < 1 || monthNumber > 12) return null;
    String[] months = new String[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    return months[monthNumber];
}
```

Also,

(1) just initialize monthName at first, perhaps to

```
String month = monthName(monthNumber);
```

(2) you should probably begin method names with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Should not enter the statement "IF" find an uninitialized variable.

Initializes monthNameFin.

Try this:

```
public String MonthName(int monthNumber){
    /*This method assigns a Name based on the users input and
    **returns the proper name of the corresponding month 
    ** @para: monthNameFin is the final name of the month
    **        rest should be self-explanatory              */

    String monthNameFin = ""; /* <----------- */

    if (monthNumber == 1)
        monthNameFin = "January";
    if (monthNumber == 2)
        monthNameFin = "February";
    if (monthNumber == 3)
        monthNameFin = "March";
    if (monthNumber == 4)
        monthNameFin = "April";
    if (monthNumber == 5)
        monthNameFin = "May";
    if (monthNumber == 6)
        monthNameFin = "June";
    if (monthNumber == 7)
        monthNameFin = "July";
    if (monthNumber == 8)
        monthNameFin = "August";
    if (monthNumber == 9)
        monthNameFin = "September";
    if (monthNumber == 10)
        monthNameFin = "October";
    if (monthNumber == 11)
        monthNameFin = "November";
    if (monthNumber == 12)
        monthNameFin = "December";

    return monthNameFin;
}
```